# FB Like box only shows on one page

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have the following code to display the [FB Like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) in a file called notify.html.

```
<div id="fb-root" class="fb_like"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" width="270" height="250" show_faces="true" border_color="black" stream="true" header="true">
</fb:like-box>
```

This file is included in all my other pages such that everything in notify.html shows up in a sidebar for all pages.

However, the FB like box only shows up on one page,, and that happens to be the page where I also have the FB registration form.

Why does it not show up in other pages?

The FB registration code on the one page the like box shows on is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
   FB.init({
      appId:'0000000000000', cookie:true,
      status:true, xfbml:true
   });
</script>
<fb:registration
  fields="[{'name':'name'},{'name':'emailEdu','description':'Your .edu Email','type':'text'},{'name':'captcha'}]"
  redirect-uri="http://myurlhere.com">
</fb:registration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the FB.init method once on every page you want to use the api with. If you only have the code from that first example and nothing else, its not working because you haven't initialised the FB object. On the registration code you have the FB init, which is why it suddenly starts working.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you're exactly copying the FB code. From their code generator on the page you referenced, you should be including the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" width="292" 
show_faces="true" border_color="" stream="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

-- but your script tag is missing the #xfbml stuff

**Also** use firebug or similar to see if you are getting any JS errors. Also check that you're not double loading the FB libs

**Added** I think the problem is that your xffbml tags are not being parsed on the other pages. Hopefully fixing the script include tag will fix it...